# How to add text next to icons and avoid parallelizable requests?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I have 30 subjects/titles, each subject/title have an icon on the left side.
I am using an `<img>` and `<p>` tags to make my icons and text look the way that I want but, once I check my website speed I get the following warning:

> This page makes 39 parallelizable requests to mywebsite.com. Increase download parallelization by distributing these requests across multiple hostnames:

Is there a way to do it without the `<img>` tag and get the same result (see picture)?

[image]

HTML

```
<div class=" row gi-icon-padding"> 
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 gi-icon" >
                        <div data-aos="fade-up">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/gi_icons/19b.png" />
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div data-aos="fade-down" >
                            <p class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 gi-name">Autoimmune Hepatitis </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS

```
.gi-icon-group {
    padding-top:30px;

    .gi-icon-padding {

        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .gi-icon {
        width: 55px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        padding-right: 10px;

    }

    .gi-name {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 0;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height:20px;

    }

}
```

Comment: you can put all of the little icons in a single sprite image. it's one of the things google uses on the serp https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo242.png

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: You'll need to google or use another part of stackoverflow for a tutorial on sprites, but I posted an example as an answer.

Comment: What's the edit you want to make to my answer? You want to replace the closing div with text?

Comment: Yess..So, google what you said ..and you were right...then, I found some issues ...I added all icons into one file, but every time I tried to add text next to each icon..the other icons show up..

Comment: I got my icons and text into a list `<ul>`

Comment: Yeah, you can't add text to that element - you would add text before/after that element. The element should just be for the image/icon. Do you still need help or you got it now?

Comment: Im trying. To fix it.i will let u know in about 15 min ..thanks

Comment: didnt work for me...how can I add text ..next to the icons? for example add Airplane Icon next to the icon

Comment: Updated my answer with an example

Comment: Great! Thanks, I just added some padding ..to separate the text from the icons...thank you so much! I never thought about the css-sprite aka sprite..thanks

Comment: Awesome, no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CSS sprite. For example, here is the sprite Google uses on their search engine result page https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo242.png

To do this, you basically combine all of your images to a single file, then use that file to serve `background-image`s in the places you would normally use an `img`. Here's an example with the google sprite, or you can inspect the SERP on google.com

```css
.sprite {
  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/jiP6Y5/nav_logo242.png') no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo {
  width: 125px;
  height: 40px;
  background-position: -20px 0;
}

.plane {
  width: 20px;
  height: 19px;
  background-position: -80px -192px;
}
```

```html
<div><span class="sprite logo"></span>text</div>
<div><span class="sprite plane"></span>text</div>
```